# How to change TextField value without having to delete it first (Flutter)

Tags: forms, flutter, input, textfield

I am trying to make a Phone Verification input field with six digits, all having max length of 1 digit.
My issue is that I want the user to be able to change the value they entered without having to delete the old value. For example, the user typed "2" to a box, and when they clicked the box and typed "3", the value should change automatically.

Comment: Please provide the code you use so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is like this.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  TextEditingController tc = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: tc,
      onChanged: (newText){
        if(newText.length == 2){
          tc.text = newText.substring(1);
          tc.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: 1));
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked just fine, thank you very much for helping out a newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the text field in a gestureDetector then use the onTap property to set the textEditingController.text value to an empty string

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, assign controllers for text fields. Now when user click on text fields and input a digit, do controllerX.clear() for that textfield in its onChange function and put the new value by controllerX.text = value. Thats it!